# Serializing Java GUI to XML

Tags: java, xml, user-interface, serialization

Here is the situation: I have hundreds of gui components, serialized as POJOs - just ObjectStream.write() and so on.
I need to maintain them, edit etc. So now I'm looking for a framework to convert my GUI to some XML of common format, like one NetBeans use.
It's shold look like this:

```
`AwesomeGuiTool.convert(java.awt.Component myGui) -> 
  <panel width="" height="">
      <label>
      <button>
  </panel>`
```

Haven't find anything like that. Already going to write it myself.

Comment: [Google Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) ?

Comment: The point is not to get an XML presentation of my POJOs, but "a some GUI editor readable XML".

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to have a look at JavaFX and the FXML format for the JavaFX GUI.

There is a pretty usable GUI editor: [JavaFX Scene Builder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html)

Maybe you can easily write some kind of converter (depends on your use-case/complexibility...)